# calling an activity from fragment activity through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

Is it possible to start an activity from fragment activity using intent

```
intent i = new intent(fragment, activity);
```

I have tried the above syntax but it is throwing me an error that this type of constructor of intent is undefined

Comment: have you search before asking this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Intent` constructor accepts two arguments. first argument is your `Context` and the second one is your `Activity` class. in your fragment, you can access your `Context` via `getActivity` method. here is what you should do :

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);
```